# runtime error project source code not found and invalid string null exception?

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

My code was running and i compiled and executed many times in 3days but suddenly error appears sourrce code not found i resolved it by installing extension of source code assembly but still there is 1 error

even i have removed connection string class but still runtime error while starting a project

[image: error picture]

check image the error appears qwhen project is run or build

code for subnew

```
 Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent() 

    End Sub
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with `C#`?

Comment: need answer its simple in same technology

Comment: what are u even trying to do, this is far from the most basic examples of setting up a connection string

Comment: my code was working sucessfully but certainly this error appears in vb.net i am expert in c#

Comment: i have removed class connection string

Comment: still same error while starting to run form

Comment: yes i have added image must check

Comment: An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: There is probably something wrong with the form constructor or initialization code.  (based on the error message)  Show the code in `Sub New` **not** a picture of it

Comment: **Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub**

Answer (score 1):

You have to use One More Slash in Your Connection String To get rid of escape Sequence
as

> Public DBConn As String = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Quotient;Integrated Security=True"

OR

> Public DBConn As String = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Quotient;Integrated Security=True"

You must put "@" sign before Connection String as it there is a Escape Sequence ("\") in Connection String

Comment: vb.net not support @ sign

Comment: check now ii have changed codwe

Comment: this Error is due to Null string reference or  Empty String reference
i updated code for connection string try that code

Comment: i have removed connectionstring class even but at runtime this throws error

Comment: even debugger not goes to form load

Comment: You have to write connection string with "\\" double backward Slash and then clean your project then compile it.

Comment: i have permanently removed class connection string but i got there is still error while executing programe nothing to do with connectionstring

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by recreating form and copy pasting contents from form1 to form3 new and then renaming it to FORM1 and deleting existing form1