# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, exception

Every time, when I try to create a datarowview it `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. Please help me to solve this.

```
For i As Integer = 0 To UsersBindingSource.Count - 1
        Dim rowData As DataRowView = UsersBindingSource.Item(i)
Next
```

Bindingsource .item(i) show the error.

Comment: What type is UsersBindingSource? If it is a _BindingSource_ could you add the code that initializes it?

Comment: there is nothing at index you are giving must change the count - 1 and tesr by putting _For i As Integer = 0 To i = *some integer for test*_

Comment: The bindingsource has not initialized manually. It binds user table of my database.  `Me.UsersTableAdapter.Fill(Me.SilexDatabaseDataSet.Users)`

Comment: This code works for all other tables. But not for this table. I cannot understand why.

Comment: after how many iterations of debugging error appears also restart visual studio

Comment: _Dim rowData As DataRowView = UsersBindingSource.Item(i).value_ must check too

Comment: the error simply says you are trying to initialize a row from null value where nothing is present while count - 1

Comment: @office302 it iterates two times only.

Comment: you are not getting values in proper way try that because you are getting whole row not its value their check and tell me  `Dim rowData As DataRowView = UsersBindingSource.Item(i).value`  also check with _.tostring()_

Comment: got it also use keyword `New`

Comment: bindingsource.item() does not have a value property

Comment: in for loop try to run code only 1 time to debug then mark end point as it is going out of bound of array where there is no value in your source `For i As Integer = 0 to i=0`

Comment: Still it gives error in item(i).

Comment: @office302 thax for your help. Finally I resolved the problem. In every iteration count become 0. Thats why it gives the exception. I assigned a static value and now it is working. Thanx.

Comment: my answer is right yahoo thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally error appears when you are exceeding you range like you have only 3 integers in an array and you are trying to use 4th one also but in your case their is no value in you datasource

```
  UsersBindingSource.Count
```

have value **zero** and you are applying operation

must check the number of values in source , you are not filling datasource

by operation

```
   UsersBindingSource.Count-1
```

you are also going to **negative**

markup if agree

Comment: And how it is possible to enter that loop if Count is 0?

Comment: zero is index he mean 1 so 2 iterations

Comment: he have problem with count it changes to zero and loop goes back to -1 now he declared static as i mentioned in comments above

Comment: Glad you have understood what happen in the code that s/he has not shown.

Comment: you are right i understand his code he have not shown there thnkyou all of you

Comment: @Steve you can also answer this i checked your profile [click-link to question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34465702/runtime-error-project-source-code-not-found-and-invalid-string-null-exception)